# When are cobordant manifolds diffeomorphic

Tags: general-topology, geometry, differential-geometry, differential-topology

I'm trying to decide when two cobordant manifolds are diffeomorphic. I believe if we have a submersion $f:M\to R$, then the pre-images of two points are diffeomorphic (they certainly are cobordant), but I'm having a hard time proving this.

Comment: Most cobordant manifolds are not diffeomorphic. As to your more precise question, if the submersion is not proper this is probably false. Try to break it with a map $\Bbb R^2 \to \Bbb R$. If the submersion is proper this follows from Ehressman's theorem.

Comment: I assume that you work with closed manifolds; then indeed the level sets in your setting are diffeomorphic. Any book on Morse theory would cover this.

Comment: yes sorry I meant proper

Comment: However, you can ask the question, when are cobordant manifolds homotopic?